# Forcing a terminal not to print Ctrl hotkeys when signals are caught

Tags: c, terminal, signals

Good day,

I'm writing my own shell in C for my school which has to resemble `bash` as closely as possible.

I have to handle signals such as Ctrl-\ and Ctrl-C as `bash` does; for this reason I'm allowed to use `signal` function. It works fine, but the thing is whenever a Ctrl-C signal is caught (starting from the second catch), a `^C` is printed.

On the net, I've found a workaround suggesting printing `"\b \b\b \b\nminishell$ "` whenever a Ctrl-C is caught, which will devour the two symbols. The thing is, since at the very first time `^C` is not printed, the print devours two symbols of my prompting, making it just `minishell` instead of `minishell$` , with the cursor incorrectly displayed.

Now I've come up with another workaround for this workaround which is to declare a static boolean to not print the baskspaces at the very first call. This doesn't help in case of Ctrl-\ though; Ctrl-\ proceeds to move my cursor to right when I attempt to write the two whitespaces that must replace the `^\`.

I don't like these workarounds and would like to know whether there is a way to instruct the terminal not to output this stuff? I'm allowed to use `tgetent`, `tgetflag`, `tgetnum`, `tgetstr`, `tgoto`, `tputs`, `tcsetattr`, `tcgetattr`, have read their man pages but nothing seems to be helpful.

Comment: These days, conventional wisdom holds that that `sigaction()` should be used instead of `signal()` for installing signal handlers.

Comment: Unfortunately, out of the signal handling function, only usage `signal()` is allowed. I can't use `sigaction()` -- it'll result in cheating and failure of the project.

Comment: Fom the commandline: `stty -ctlecho` . in tcsetattr(), the flag is named `ECHOCTL`. This flag controls the way characters below space (except NUL, TAB, CR, LF, which are still special) are **echoed** by the terminal.

Comment: Are you sure that your handler is getting invoked the second and subsequent times?

Comment: *Unfortunately, out of the signal handling function, only usage `signal()` is allowed.* That's asinine. Your instructor might just as well be forcing you to write your code by chiseling it into stone tablets.

Comment: Also, you're not calling `printf()` from within your signal handler, are you?  [\[A\] signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188)  POSIX extends that to allow you to [safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you type a key on a terminal, two things happen

- the character is *echoed* (displayed) on this terminal
- the character is sent (over the line) to the attached program

Both these actions can be controlled via termios/tcsetattr(): a different character(s) can be sent or echoed, some can be suppressed, etc. (some/most of these actions take place in the terminal-*driver* , but this is not relevant here)

Demonstration: using `tcsetattr()` to control the echoing of the terminal:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _SVID_SOURCE 1
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

struct termios termios_save;

void reset_the_terminal(void)
{
tcsetattr(0, 0, &termios_save );
}

sig_atomic_t the_flag = 0;
void handle_the_stuff(int num)
{
char buff[4];
buff[0] = '[';
buff[2] = '0' + num%10;
num /= 10;
buff[1] = '0' + num%10;
buff[3] = ']';
write(0, buff, sizeof buff);
the_flag = 1;
}

int main (void)
{
int rc;
int ch;
struct termios termios_new;

rc = tcgetattr(0, &termios_save );
if (rc) {perror("tcgetattr"); exit(1); }

rc = atexit(reset_the_terminal);
if (rc) {perror("atexit"); exit(1); }

termios_new = termios_save;
termios_new.c_lflag &= ~ECHOCTL;
rc = tcsetattr(0, 0, &termios_new );
if (rc) {perror("tcsetattr"); exit(1); }

signal(SIGINT, handle_the_stuff);

printf("(pseudoshell)Start typing:\n" );
while(1) {
        ch = getc(stdin);
        if (the_flag) {
                printf("Saw the signal, last character was %02x\n", (unsigned) ch);
                break;
                }
        }

exit (0);
}
```

Comment: thank you, i finally understood what `tcsetattr()` is used for. but I have another problem: on the man page, it's stated: "(not in POSIX)"; however, the school's computers are running macOS. I printed the gotten oflag, cleared the `ECHOCTL` bit, printed it again and the number remained unchanged:( Should I then seek a workaround instead?

Comment: See the manpage, this is where the `_SVID_SOURCE` is intended for. But: if your system/ttydriver doesn't support it you'll lose ...

Comment: unfortunately, `#ifdef _SVID_SOURCE` fails. can I define it myself or maybe try installing some packages? I'm accepting your answer since it'd work on Linux

Comment: You need to define _SVID_SOURCE (or _BSD_SOURCE) yourself. But: if your terminal driver doesn't support the ECHOCTL, you could fall back on raw mode (see the other answer) BTW: "MacOS" is a BSD rip-off.

Comment: good day, wanted to thank you again, and tell that it turned out that the function indeed works on my school's computer: I ran your code and the terminal didn't output `^C`. however, for some reason, it just doesn't work in my program's `main()`. it only works if I put it inside the signal handler, for some reason... why? moreover, when I run `stty` inside my shell, it still displays `echoctl` among `lflags`. it gets reset by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The way to set the console such a SW may intercept all typed chars is to set the terminal in RAW MODE. The problems this way may present are that all keys that aren't in the ASCII 0-255 space, such as `è`, `ì`, `à` will be received from the console as a bytes sequence and all the function and control keys included cursors and backspace will not accomplish any action, some code such as `CR`, `LF` and some `ANSI` sequence may accomplish actions when are read from the input channel and rewritten on the output channel.

To set the terminal in raw mode you have to use the function `cfmakeraw` followed by the function `tcsetattr`.

The code below implements a simple but not very good implemented terminal, anyway I think this code is a good point to start. In any case, the code flow and the error control must be at least better arranged.

The code writes all sequence of ASCII char that enter into the console when a key is typed. All chars that have value smaller then 32 or greater then 126 will be written as `[HEX-CODE]`

I.E. hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the console will be written `[1B]`, the code of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will be written as `[03]`, <kbd>F1</kbd> will be `[1B]OP`, <kbd>F11</kbd> will be `[1B][23~`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> will be `[0D]`.

If you will hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> `[18]` will be written and the program stops, but this behaviour is under SW control as you can see in the code.

Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>      // Standard input/output definitions
#include <string.h>     // String function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions (struct termios)

#include <sys/ioctl.h> // Used for TCGETS2, which is required for custom baud rates
#include <sys/select.h> // might be used to manage select

int setAttr(int ch, int resetToOld);

#define IN 0
#define OUT 1

typedef struct TermCap
{
    int fd;
    struct termios oldTermios;
    struct termios newTermios;
    // fd_set fds; // might be used to manage select
} TermCap;

TermCap m_termCap[2];

int main()
{
    int i,ex=0;
    char msg;
    char buff[20];

    m_termCap[IN].fd=STDIN_FILENO;
    m_termCap[OUT].fd=STDOUT_FILENO;

    // Gets STDIN config and set raw config
    setAttr(IN,0);

    // Gets STDOUT config and set raw config
    setAttr(OUT,0);

    // Console loop ... the console terminates when ^X is intercepted.
    do {
        do {
            i=read(m_termCap[IN].fd,&msg,1);
            if (i>0){
                if (msg<32 || msg>126) {
                    sprintf(buff,"[%02X]",(unsigned char)msg);
                    write(m_termCap[OUT].fd,buff,4);
                    if (msg==24)
                        ex=1;
                }else{
                    write(m_termCap[OUT].fd,&msg,i);
                }
            }
            usleep(10000); // a minimal delay of 10 millisec
        } while(i>0 && !ex);
    } while(!ex);

    // Reset console to initial state.
    setAttr(IN,1);
    setAttr(OUT,1);

    printf("\r\n\nThe end!");
    return 0;
}

int setAttr(int ch, int resetToOld)
{
    int retVal=0;
    int i;

    if (!resetToOld) {
        // Read old term config
        i=tcgetattr(m_termCap[ch].fd, &m_termCap[ch].oldTermios);
        if (i==-1) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    m_termCap[ch].newTermios = m_termCap[ch].oldTermios;

    if (!resetToOld) {
        // Terminal in raw mode
        cfmakeraw(&m_termCap[ch].newTermios);
    }

    i=tcsetattr(m_termCap[ch].fd, TCSANOW, &m_termCap[ch].newTermios);

    if (i==-1) {
        retVal = 2;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```c
void signalHandler(int signo){
 if(signo==SIGINT){
  printf("\b\b  \b\b");
  fflush(NULL);
  printf("\nHello World\n");    
 }
}
```

In my shell it seems to work fine. The first printf and fflush is what you have to implement in your handler. The printf after that is just a way for me to show you that you can, then, do whatever you want after the `^C` not appearing.

Why does this make it not appear? In the first printf I erase the characters by using backspaces and spaces. As stdout is buffered by default and I didn't want to use a newline character, I flushed the buffer manually.

Comment: You cannot use printf() and friends in a signal handler.