# How to remove characters(^\), ctrl + \(SIGQUIT), from STDIN in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

In bash, `ctrl` + `\` command, we can't see the characters `^\`

If I type `ctrl` + `\` , in my program, it works like a SIGQUIT signal in bash program.
But I can see the charater `^\` ...

How to remove `^\` character in STDIN???

Here is my code about terminos structure.

```
void set_input_mode(void)
{
    int vdisable;

    if ((vdisable = (fpathconf(0, _PC_VDISABLE) < 0)))
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
    term.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;   
    term.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;    
    term.c_lflag |= ICANON;  
    term.c_cc[VQUIT] = vdisable;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);
}
```

Comment: I think you may use the info in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68602211/forcing-a-terminal-not-to-print-ctrl-hotkeys-when-signals-are-caught/68602964#68602964

Comment: Don't conflate `stdin` and the terminal.  You are seeing `^\` on the terminal.  There is nothing on stdin for the currently running foreground process.